# Mint function of ERC20 reverts, when called from another contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, erc-20, mint

So, I am trying to call a mint function which is present in my ERC20 token contract, which is a standard open Zeppelin Contract, From another Contract.

I am using Interface to call the mint function, from my staking smart contract. But it keeps getting reverted.

I tried the Remix debug as well but, I am not able to find the reason.

My code is as mentioned below:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

interface Token
{
    function transfer(address _To, uint256 _Amount) external returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns(uint);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) external returns(bool);
}

contract Staking
{
    Token ELONToken;

    // 2 months = (60*24*60*60)
    uint256 public StakeDuration = 1;

    // 10% intreset foer the Stakers.
    uint8 IntrestRate = 10;

    uint256 TotalStakers;

    // Structure to hold details regarding the stakers.
    struct StakerInfo
    {
        uint256 startTS;
        uint256 endTS;
        uint256 amount;
        uint256 claimed;
    }

    //mapping which maps to the structure inorder to have the details of each staker.
    mapping(address => StakerInfo) public StakerInfos;

    //mapping to hold addresses of stakers.
    mapping(address => bool) public StakedAddress;

    constructor(Token ERC20_add)
    {
        require(address(ERC20_add)!= address(0),"Enter Valid Contract address");
        ELONToken = ERC20_add;
        TotalStakers = 0;
    }

    // Function to check balance
    function CheckBalance(address account) external view returns(uint256)
    {
        return(ELONToken.balanceOf(account));
    }

    // Function to call the Mint from ERC20
    function MintTokens(address To, uint256 _amount) public returns(bool)
    {
        ELONToken.mint(To, _amount);
        return(true);
    }
    
    //Function to Stake Tokens in the smart Contract.
    function StakeTokens(uint256 _Stakeamount) external payable
    {
        require(_Stakeamount > 0, "Stake amount cannot be Zero");
        require(StakedAddress[msg.sender] == false,"You have already Staked");
        require(ELONToken.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= _Stakeamount, "Insufficient Tokens");
       
        ELONToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _Stakeamount);
        unchecked
        {
            ++TotalStakers;
        }
        StakedAddress[msg.sender] = true;
        StakerInfos[msg.sender] = StakerInfo({
            startTS: block.timestamp,
            endTS: block.timestamp + StakeDuration,
            amount: _Stakeamount,
            claimed: 0
        });
    }

    function ClaimRewards(uint256 ClaimAmount) external returns (bool)
    {
        require(StakedAddress[msg.sender] == true,"You have not Staked any Tokens");
        require(StakerInfos[msg.sender].endTS < block.timestamp, "Stake Time is not over yet");
        require(ClaimAmount <= StakerInfos[msg.sender].amount,"Not enough Tokens to Claim");
        
        uint256 Mintamount = ClaimAmount*IntrestRate/100;
        uint256 totalReward = ClaimAmount + Mintamount; 
        //MintTokens(Mintamount);
        StakerInfos[msg.sender].claimed += totalReward;

        ELONToken.transfer(msg.sender, totalReward);
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you take a look at the interface I have mentioned some functions which I want to use from the Open-Zeppelin ERC20.
But when I try to use the Mint function as you can see in the above code, it reverts.

The error I get is as follows:

**The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.**

I am not trying to send any ether to it so, no sense in making it payable, I am minting new tokens to its address.

**Thank you if you took the time to go through this and help me out, I really appreciate it!!!**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error message you're getting is a generic one that is not related to your specific problem. The issue is most likely related to the fact that you are calling the `mint` function from your `Staking` contract, but the `mint` function is not defined in the `Token` interface.

To fix this, you should update your `Token` interface to include the `mint` function. Here's an updated version of the interface that includes the `mint` function:

```
interface Token {
    function transfer(address _To, uint256 _Amount) external returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns(uint);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) external returns(bool);
}
```

Make sure to update the `Token` interface in your `Staking` contract as well. Once you've done this, you should be able to call the `mint` function from your `Staking` contract without any issues.